# IIS 404 Error even when file exists?

Tags: iis, nginx, web, localhost

I have been working with IIS 7 for a while and it has worked fine until it just suddenly started throwing 404 errors for my multiple websites even though they actually exist. All of the configurations seems fine (path, default document) but not a single file, no matter the format or location will be loaded.

Another strange thing is that everything works when I try to access the websites via localhost or 127.0.0.1 but not through my external IP.

Does anyone know why this could happen and how I can fix it?

Edit:

It appears this 404 page is not the built in IIS error page. It is associated with nginx but I'm not sure where the file is located on my server or why my pages are being intercepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns at the server was hijacked by Morfeus F***ing Scanner, which I was not aware was even a thing until this happened. It's activity showed up in the server access logs. I basically had to reset the entire server. It was quite a chore.